# What are the STB and DIO pins on an IC

Tags: pins

What are **DIO** and **STB** pins in below IC?

[image]

If **DIO** means digital input or output, then how to set it to Input or Output mode? Is it using **STB**?

Comment: Information like this is ALWAYS available in the datasheet. If you cannot find the datasheet for the part, do not buy it. If you can find the datasheet but it doesn't say, then don't buy anything from the manufacturer. The one exception is for chips that are basically identical across many, many manufacturers and are all drop in replacements for each other...like RAM chips. But even these will often give a brief descripton of the pin.

Comment: google translate can help you out a bit with that datasheet.  DIO is both in and out according to what I read.

Answer (score 3):

This is spelled out in the [TM1668 data sheet](https://www.sunrom.com/get/348055)

[image]

How you use it is also spelled out there:

[image]

You can think of the STB as a kind of chip-select. The DIO is both an input and an output, so this communication protocol works a lot like I2C with an extra chip-select.

Comment: I would be more inclined to think of this as an SPI variant than an I2C variant. The STB pin serves the same role as the CS line in SPI, acting both as a chip select and as a start of transaction indicator.

Answer (score 1):

Strobe and Data Input/Output

Google TM1668, pick your favorite source for a datasheet.